# Looping over an array in an object from the object

Tags: javascript

i tried to loop over an array nested in an object and log it to my console but the console keeps logging out "undefined".

```js
let dogspace = {
    name: "rusty",
    friends: ["ruby", "frun", "geo"],
    print: function (){
        this.friends.forEach(friend => {
            return friend
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing anything in the for each. You are just returning stuff. Which does nothing really in forEach.

Try this:

```js
let dogspace = {
name: "rusty",
friends: ["ruby", "frun", "geo"],
print: function() {
    this.friends.forEach(friend => {
       console.log(friend);
    });
}}

dogspace.print();
```